# building Gtest framework in LINUX

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

I have downloaded the GTest sourcecode googletest-release-1.8.0.tar.gz (from : github ) and extracted it. (working on CentOS)
After that I ran following commands:

1. cd googletest-release-1.8.0\googletest.
2. cmake CMakeLists.txt.
   Output:
   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: gtestframework/googletest-release-1.8.0/googletest
3. make.
   Output:
   [ 50%] Built target gtest
   [100%] Built target gtest_main

After this I copied the file libgtest_main.a and libgtest.a into /usr/lib.

4. cd googletest-release-1.8.0\googlemock\gtest.
5. Copied libgtest_main.so  libgtest.so  libGTest.so in /usr/lib folder.

   6. cd gtestframework\Testcode //{2 C++ files inside Testcode}
   7. cmake CMakeLists.txt.
   8. make.

I got this error:

```
Linking CXX executable runTests
CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/tests.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
tests.cpp:(.text+0x95a): undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
tests.cpp:(.text+0xa14): undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/tests.cpp.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int, double>(char const*, char const*, int const&, double const&)':
tests.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal18CmpHelperEQFailureIidEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_[_ZN7testing8internal18CmpHelperEQFailureIidEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_]+0x6c): undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool)'
CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/tests.cpp.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<double, double>(char const*, char const*, double const&, double const&)':
tests.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal18CmpHelperEQFailureIddEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_[_ZN7testing8internal18CmpHelperEQFailureIddEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_]+0x6c): undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::string const&, std::string const&, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [runTests] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CMakeLists.txt file content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

Comment: Are you linking against the gtest libraries?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just for reference: CMake file content: 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
 
# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 
# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)

Comment: Please put that part of your `CMakeLists.txt` directly in the question, not in a comment (among other things, the comment isn't formatted).

Comment: You say: "I copied the file libgtest_main.a and libgtest.a into /usr/lib." And later
you say: "Copied libgtest_main.so libgtest.so libGTest.so in /usr/lib folder."
`*.a` is not `*.so`. So which of those things did you actually do? Or
did you do both? It matters.

Comment: I did both in the order mentioned above.